# BASIC comand: RIGHT$

Tags: basic

Is there a screen about little script in BASIC language with SmallBasic interpreter. Once i write the input for example: BANANE it should return a  word written backwards, as example: ENANAB. The compiler strangely after i run 
the script with "Ctrl+r" keyboard command doesn't ask me to input something. 
What could be thew mistake?

```
   `INPUT A$
    K=LEN(A$)
    B$= " "
    FOR I=1 TO K
    A$=LEFT$(A$, K-I+1)
    RIGHT$(A$,1)
    B$=B$+L$
    NEXT I
    PRINT B$
    END`
```

I expect a word written backwards for example: "BANANA" became "ANANAB"

But the compiler says me that: "The value returned from RIGHT was not assigned".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87m6a.png)

Answer (score 3):

As an old QBASIC nerd, I'm so happy to answer a BASIC question in 2019.

RIGHT$ doesn't touch the string you passed to it. Instead, it computes a new string with the letters reversed, and *returns* it.

Try this:

```
A$ = RIGHT$(A$,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer to reverse an input value:

```
INPUT A$
K = LEN(A$)
FOR I = 1 TO K
    A$ = LEFT$(A$, K - I + 1)
    L$ = RIGHT$(A$, 1)
    B$ = B$ + L$
NEXT I
PRINT B$
END
```

Or a more simple way to reverse a string:

```
INPUT A$
FOR L = LEN(A$) TO 1 STEP -1
    B$ = B$ + MID$(A$, L, 1)
NEXT L
PRINT B$
END
```